# Big-O Analysis Of Function, Replace All Vowels in a String With A Char

Tags: c++, big-o

I am not sure if I am doing my big-O analysis correctly.

This is a function which replaces all the vowels in a string with a specified character.

I have chosen to compare every character in the string to a string of constant size which contains all of the vowels.

Given that the input string can scale upwards in size, but the vowel string is constant in size, I think the big-O analysis is O(n * m) rather than O(n * n), where n is the input string, and m is the vowel string.

I am thinking that it should just be O(n) and not even O(n * m), given that the second for loop iterates over a constant number of elements, so that would be dropped?

I'd greatly appreciate it if someone can correct me.

```
using namespace std;

string replaceVowels(string str, char ch) {

    string vowels = "aeiouyAEIOUY";

    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) { //O(n)

        for(int j = 0; j < vowels.size(); j++) { //O(m)
            if (str[i] == vowels[j])
                str[i] = ch;
        }
    }

    // O(n * m) or O(n) or O(n * n)?
    return str;
}
```

Comment: It's O(n). m is a constant and doesn't count.

Comment: Hay I do not know if you have seen my answer, is it helpful or should I delete it?

Answer (score -1):

In [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) you can ignore all constant (strictly positive) factors.

This means that (since m=12 is constant) **O(n * m)** = **O(n)**, so both would technically be correct, but of course **O(n)** is what one would say (much like we were taught to answer "one half" instead of "two quarters" in elementary school).

That is it, at least in theory. In practice however, it is sometimes a subjective task to determine what counts as a constant, and what can be arbitrarily large. In this case for example, we use the fact that sizeof(int) is constant (otherwise **i < str.size()** wouldn't take constant time), but we still assume that **n** has no upper bound (otherwise **O(n)=O(1)**). *Technically*, these assumptions can't both be true, but we make them anyway in much the same way we assume 0 air friction in physics to fit a simpler model.

Comment: I can't get behind an answer that tries to say O(n) = O(1). I get what you're trying to say, but they're not the same.

Comment: Next time you'll say that O(n^100) is technically O(1) because everything is bounded by a constant because this is C++ and the max value of n is INT_MAX.

Comment: The OP code isn't guaranteed to ever stop. For instance, if str.size() > INT_MAX, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I realize my second part was confusing. My whole point with it was the last sentence that it is sometimes subjective what counts as a constant. I'm not sure if you interpreted my **O(n)=O(1)** part as being a general statement (which would be mathematically false); it was meant as a statement about this application. I will take your feedback and try to clarify though!